# Async Nonblocking Multicast with Camel

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, nonblocking, spring-camel

I have two query :
1. Can we have non blocking async routes in camel. I do see async with `seda` but then if offloads work to other thread that blocks. 
2. If so can we use multicast in such routes. 
Following is my multistep camel route which seems to work. But not sure if it is async or non blocking async.

```
from("direct:multiStep")
             .to("bean:routeHandler?method=monoReturningMethod1")
             .process(new UnwrapStreamProcessor())
             .to("bean:routeHandler?method=monoReturningMethod2")
             .process(new UnwrapStreamProcessor())
```

Above works and web request has response from both `monoReturningMethod`. In this case I want to make sure all process is non blocking.

For multicast I am experimenting with following route. Not sure where to put `UnwrapStreamProcessor`. I have tried to put it after `end()` but it does not work. Do I need a custom `Processor` ? Or how can I tie all `Mono` returns in one ?

```
from("direct:incoming")
         .multicast()
         .parallelProcessing()
         .to("bean:routeHandler?method=monoReturningMethod1", "bean:routeHandler?method=monoReturningMethod2")
         .end()
```

I am using apache `camel 3.0.1 with spring boot starter.

```
@Component("routeHandler")
public class RouteHandler {
     Mono<Entity> monoReturningMethod1(Exchange exchange) {
          //make some WebClient request which returns Mono.
     }
     Mono<Entity> monoReturningMethod2(Exchange exchange) {
          //make some WebClient request which returns Mono.
     }
}
```

This route handles incoming web request. How to make all route processing non blocking and async. I have tried using `process(new UnwrapStreamProcessor())` as process step after `monoReturningMehtod` and if I do in sequence it works. But it does not work with multicast and give original message overwrite not allowed. 
Any suggestions ?

PS : I am initiating my async flow like following :
`producerTemplate.asyncSend("RouteName", exchange)`

Answer (score 0):

[According to this page](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/asynchronous-routing-engine.html), all [EIPs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) are supported by the async routing engine, but not all [endpoint types (components)](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/). Some components have only limited support, i.e. they can only consume or produce asynchronous.

You can use the [Threads DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/async.html) in your route to tell Camel that from the point forwards, the messages should be routed asynchronous in a new thread.